# My apples are turning black and falling off the tree

Tags: fruit-trees, apples

I live in Kentucky and my apple tree has apples turning black and falling off the tree.  Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Some pictures might help. Has there been unusual weather? Too hot or cold? Too wet or dry? Anything else unusual? Any whacky chemicals nearby?